# How can I use ggplot to produce multiple plots within one pipe

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

So I was using ggplot to create three different plots, and they are using the same data frame. Everything is very similar to the other. The codes below worked pretty well. However, I felt bad about repeating them over and over again. Is there any way I can simplify it a bit?

| wday | cat_number | cat_size | cat_age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mon | some number | not important | some number |
| Tue | some number | not important | some number |

```
smelly_cat %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=wday, y=cat_number)) +
  geom_bar()
smelly_cat %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=wday,y=cat_size)) +
  geom_bar()
smelly_cat %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=wday,y=cat_age)) +
  geom_bar()
```

Comment: seems the table format just crashed

Comment: But the idea is that the wday and cat_size, cat_age, cat_number stuff are just different columns in the data frame

Answer (score 0):

Using `iris` as an example here.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)

df <- iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarize(across(everything(), mean))
df <- melt(df, id.vars = "Species")
```

I am using reshape2's `melt()` to get this table:

```
      Species     variable value
1      setosa Sepal.Length 5.006
2  versicolor Sepal.Length 5.936
3   virginica Sepal.Length 6.588
4      setosa  Sepal.Width 3.428
5  versicolor  Sepal.Width 2.770
6   virginica  Sepal.Width 2.974
7      setosa Petal.Length 1.462
8  versicolor Petal.Length 4.260
9   virginica Petal.Length 5.552
10     setosa  Petal.Width 0.246
11 versicolor  Petal.Width 1.326
12  virginica  Petal.Width 2.026
```

Now all y values are in the same column and I can plot them. You can then use `fill` in your `aes()` to define a grouping variable. Like so:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=Species,y=value,fill=variable)) +
  geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat = "identity")
```

[image]

In your `geom_bar()` you define the positioning ("stacked" for stacked bars, "dodge" for grouped bars) and use `stat = "identity"` to not have R do any aggregations.

If your y values are on different scales you might not want to have them in the same graph. You can use `facet_grid()` to have them separated, this would look like so:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=Species,y=value)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + facet_grid(. ~ variable)
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think that answers the question. OP wants to know if there's a way of avoiding the three pipes when using the same data set, not how to combine three plots into one